# Can a lattice modifier be used to scale one end of a complex object while holding the other end unscaled, without bending any lines?

Tags: lattice

[image: guitar neck]In trying to do this with a lattice modifier I find that the straight edges of my object become curved. I want to scale the object a certain amount at one end, not at all at the other end, and I want the scaling to be applied all along the length of the object in a linear fashion, i.e. in proportion to the distance from end to end. (The "ends" of the object are along the Y axis.)

I want to widen a guitar neck slightly at the end that attaches to the guitar body, while holding the width at the "nut" (where it joins the headstock) constant, and keeping the sides straight.

Comment: could you please show a screenshot? You have a linear option in the Proportional Editing

Comment: i just don't understand how you want to scale something without stretching/compressing edges? And of course, if it is subdivided, it will "bend" the object.

Comment: IMHO you can only scale very simple objects like cubes, pyramids without bending. But not complex objects.

Comment: @moonboots I added a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there is no simple solution. I solved it in Python by moving each point in the matrix along the X-axis by a factor that is determined by the geometry of the current and target outer edges of the guitar neck, and the given that the target guitar neck must also have straight edges. I'm pretty sure there is no built-in Blender method of doing something like this.

Specifically, I define a line that follows the outer edge of the current neck, and another line that will represent the target position of the new outer edge. Then, for any point (x,y,z) in the matrix, the y value points to two points on those two lines with that same y value, and the ratio of the two points' x values is the factor I use to change the x value of the point. The y and z values for each matrix point remain the same.